# generate word file through open xml

Tags: openxml

I am using openxml to generate my word file that contains user input messages and attachment if there are any. Now, I am stuck in a situation where I don't know how to display PDF /JPEG/JPG if user attached such things with the inputted message.

Is there any way I can show the above attached in my generated word file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has the specific example of adding the images to the document.  The sample code you could use is provided here.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb497430%28v=office.14%29.aspx